# MorseCode Converter in Java

Tags: java, morse-code

Please help me to solve the problem:

I have two lists: `Letter` (containing all letters) and `Symbol` (containing all morse code symbols). And I need two write a method for converting a word into morse code. In my opinion the idea should be next: split the word into letters and then replase the letter with the symbol.

```
class Morse {
   void Code(char let){
   // what should I write here?
   }
}
```

Comment: "// what should I write here?"  Code.  If you come up with a more specific question, feel free to ask it.  As an aside, method names should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: i dont't realize how the algorithm (code) should look like.

Comment: You need Map<Character, String>.

Answer (score 2):

You need to map Letter to Symbol. I would normally prefer a Map, that you can init by

```
Map<Letter,Symbol> morseCode = new HashMap<Letter, Symbol>();
for (int i =0; i< YOURLETTERS.size(); i++) {
   morseCode.put(YOURLETTERS.get(i), YOURSYMBOLS.get(i));
}
```

Then, as you said, move through your Message String character by character, lookup the Mapping and add the symbol to a result (array or list, maybe)

Answer (score 1):

Create a conversion table form the two lists and use that.

```
public class Morse {

    List<Character> letters = ...
    List<String> codes = ...

    Map<Character, String> conversionTable = new HashMap<Character, String>();

    public void init() {
        int t = 0;
        for(Character c : letters) {
            conversionTable.put(c, codes.get(t));
            t++;
        }
    }

    public String code(char let){
        return conversionTable.get(let);
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be better to out initialization to.. initialization block.

Comment: how does conversion table looks like?